# Error in Numba function: "tuple index out of range" when using custom class for sparse matrix

Tags: python, tuples, numba, mode

I'm encountering an issue with a `Numba-optimized` function that involves a custom class for representing a sparse matrix. The error message I'm getting is:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
tuple index out of range
During: typing of static-get-item at z:\2023-2024\Python Labs\E0\TEST\Untitled-3.py (73)

File "z:\2023-2024\Python Labs\E0\TEST\Untitled-3.py", line 73:
def numba_csc_ndarray_dot2(a: csc_matrix, b: np.ndarray):
out = np.zeros((a.shape[0], b.shape[1]))
^
```

The problem seems to be related to indexing tuples, and it occurs in the following code snippet:

```
class csc_matrix:
    def __init__(self, data: np.array, indices: np.array, indptr: np.array, shape: tuple):
        self.data = data
        self.indices = indices
        self.indptr = indptr
        self.shape = shape@numba.jit(nopython=True)

class MatrixType(types.Type):
    def __init__(self, dtype):
        self.dtype = dtype
        self.data = types.Array(self.dtype, 1, 'C')
        self.indices = types.Array(types.int64, 1, 'C')
        self.indptr = types.Array(types.int64, 1, 'C')
        self.shape = types.UniTuple(types.int64, 2)
        super(MatrixType, self).__init__('csc_matrix')

@typeof_impl.register(csc_matrix)
def typeof_matrix(val, c):
    data = typeof_impl(val.data, c)
    return MatrixType(data.dtype)

@register_model(MatrixType)
class MatrixModel(models.StructModel):
    def __init__(self, dmm, fe_type):
        members = [('data', fe_type.data),('indices', fe_type.indices),('indptr', fe_type.indptr),('shape', fe_type.shape),]
        models.StructModel.__init__(self, dmm, fe_type, members)

make_attribute_wrapper(MatrixType, 'data', 'data')
make_attribute_wrapper(MatrixType, 'indices', 'indices')
make_attribute_wrapper(MatrixType, 'indptr', 'indptr')
make_attribute_wrapper(MatrixType, 'shape', 'shape')

def make_matrix(context, builder, typ, **kwargs):
    return cgutils.create_struct_proxy(typ)(context, builder, **kwargs)

@unbox(MatrixType)
def unbox_matrix(typ, obj, c):
    data = c.pyapi.object_getattr_string(obj, 'data')
    indices = c.pyapi.object_getattr_string(obj, 'indices')
    indptr = c.pyapi.object_getattr_string(obj, 'indptr')
    shape = c.pyapi.object_getattr_string(obj, 'shape')
    matrix = make_matrix(c.context, c.builder, typ)
    matrix.data = c.unbox(typ.data, data).value
    matrix.indices = c.unbox(typ.indices, indices).value
    matrix.indptr = c.unbox(typ.indptr, indptr).value
    matrix.shape = c.unbox(typ.shape, shape).value
    for att in [data, indices, indptr, shape]:
        c.pyapi.decref(att)
    is_error = cgutils.is_not_null(c.builder, c.pyapi.err_occurred())

    return NativeValue(matrix._getvalue(), is_error=is_error)

@box(MatrixType)
def box_matrix(typ, val, c):
    matrix = make_matrix(c.context, c.builder, typ)
    classobj = c.pyapi.unserialize(c.pyapi.serialize_object(csc_matrix))
    data_obj = c.box(typ.data, matrix.data)
    indices_obj = c.box(typ.indices, matrix.indices)
    indptr_obj = c.box(typ.indptr, matrix.indptr)
    shape_obj = c.box(typ.shape, matrix.shape)
    matrix_obj = c.pyapi.call_function_objargs(classobj, (data_obj, indices_obj, indptr_obj, shape_obj))
    return matrix_obj

def numba_csc_ndarray_dot2(a: csc_matrix, b: np.ndarray):

    out = np.zeros((a.shape[0], b.shape[1]))   

    for j in range(b.shape[1]):
        for i in range(b.shape[0]):
            for k in range(a.indptr[i], a.indptr[i + 1]):
                out[a.indices[k], j] += a.data[k] * b[i, j]

rows, cols = 100, 100
density = 0.1
sparse_coo = random(rows, cols, density=density, format='coo')
data = sparse_coo.data
indices = sparse_coo.row
indptr = sparse_coo.col
shape = (rows, cols)
matrix_A = csc_matrix(sparse_coo.data, sparse_coo.row, sparse_coo.col, shape=(rows, cols))

vector_b = np.random.rand(cols)

solution_x =numba_csc_ndarray_dot2(matrix_A,vector_b )


print("Matrix A:")
print(matrix_A.toarray())
print("\nVector b:")
print(vector_b)
print("\nSolution x:")
print(solution_x)
```

I suspect that either `a.indices[k]` or `a.data[k]` is resulting in a tuple, causing the "tuple index out of range" error. I've added some debugging print statements, and the output indicates unexpected tuple values.

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: You can't use special Scipy objects within Numba. Please make at least a MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Remember that a tuple or list of non-zero length N has a valid index range of -N to N-1. You need to debug your code to determine the size of the tuple (in this case) and compare that information with the index value being used

Comment: The error message should include information about which line caused the error. Please include this in your post as well. Also, if "... the output indicates unexpected tuple values.", then include the output as well.

Comment: The updated error message shows that the error occurred in the `out = np.zeros((a.shape[0], b.shape[1]))`. This indicates that the cause is likely the shape of argument `a` or `b`. Note that the shape is also a tuple.